# How to view errors on Qt WebView control?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I think my web page has some JavaScript errors that make QWebView to not work. Is there some simple way to see JS errors while I'm running the debug build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `javaScriptConsoleMessage` function:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage

As the documentation says, the default implementation does nothing...you can dump it as debug output, or whatever.  See also this article:

[Redirecting JavaScript console messages in a Qt hybrid application (Internet Archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140815085510/http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Redirecting_JavaScript_console_messages_in_a_Qt_hybrid_application)

Comment: All the links are dead :(

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow I went ahead and updated them to current links, but someday I'll be dead too...so people who notice should find the updated references and make a "suggested edit"...